# How can the organizer name be displayed with the Outlook meeting reminder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have meeting reminders set to pop-up in Outlook. When it appears it displays the subject, date and time, and location. I'd also like it to show the organizers name without having to open the appointment. Can this be done?

My reason is I have a lot of meetings with new people, and it helpful to have a quick reminder of their name before they walk in the door.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is out Outlook calendar reminders are designed. The workaround is to manually change the subject of the Calendar entry to include the organizer's name.